# How can I import a database schema into MS Access 2003 from sql text file?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a database schema generated in a text file (DDL - MS Access compliant).

Where is the option in MS Access to import that schema into an empty database ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any import for DDL.

However, DDL contains the definition for the schema.

You simply have the execute DDL as you would any query.

Either create a query, put it in sql mode, paste your ddl, and execute

or....

Create a VBA Sub to essentially do the same:   currentdb.execute SQL

Good Luck

Comment: sorry - it doesn't work,  only DML statments are supported in querries

Comment: Not true about only DML -- Jet/ACE supports a limited set of DDL commands, certainly enough to create a schema from scratch, assuming compatible data types.

Answer (score 0):

To execute a SQL DDL in the SQL View of a Query object, you may need to change the Access user interface to [ANSI-92 Query Mode](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/access/HP030704831033.aspx). While the 'traditional' query mode (ANSI-89 Query Mode) supports a SQL DDL syntax it is very limited.

The Access database engine can only execute one SQL statement (DML, DDL or DCL) at a time. To execute a SQL script consisting of multiple SQL statement, you need something to parse individual SQL statements, so it really helps if your script has semicolon `;` characters separating them, then execute each statement on at a time i.e. synchronously. If you are doing this in VBA code you are better off using ADO because it always uses ANSI-92 Query Mode.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/180841

Answer (score 0):

I have been very succesful with reverse / forward engineering MS Access databases with [Dezign for Databases](http://www.datanamic.com) by Datanamic. It reads all kinds of DDL scripts (from almost all available database) and can translate between different databases. There is a free trial available.