# How to import ddl database file to MS Access?

Tags: ms-access, rational-rose

I have a logical model and a database generated from it. How can I export database from Rational rose and import it to MS Access? I managed to export database as ***.ddl** file.
[image]

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153471/how-can-i-import-a-database-schema-into-ms-access-2003-from-sql-text-file, where the answers do not include the command line tool option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was answered, as well as can be done, in *[How can I import a database schema into MS Access 2003 from sql text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153471/how-can-i-import-a-database-schema-into-ms-access-2003-from-sql-text-file)* The process is cumbersome, and does not lend itself well to automation.

A possible more practical solution is to use a command line tool and run the DDL as a script. See http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/JET_Database/Manipulation_tools for a list of tools (unchecked).

The [JetSQLConsole](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jetsqlconsole/) command line tool at SourceForce is current and can implement what you require.